# Wordpress Permalinks not saving

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have hosted a WordPress site in AWS EC2 and migrated my local to AWS. Now the home page is working fine, but other pages are not opening. It is returning 404. Tried the following in .htaccess-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

then in apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Still no luck. I tried changing the permalink structure, but it is not saving. I keep clicking on the Save Changes button, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict with one of the plugin installed. So, I disabled all the plugins and it was working. Then, one by one I started activating and parallelly checking the functionality and finally found the culprit plugin.